# Pulling from existing repo and updating another repo error?

Tags: git

I want to clone a repository on Github, work on some code, and then push it into my personal repo. Basically I want to be able to pull code from one repo that someone else periodically posts, but then push my code to my own repo. I have a Macbook, if that helps.

What I've done so far:

1. Created an empty repo on Github
2. Cloned it into a folder I made on Desktop (git clone *URL*)
3. Added the remote repo (the one I pull from) in that folder (git remote add *Name* *URL*)
4. Tried pushing files to my repo (git add *file*, git commit, etc.).

I was hoping for it to allow me to push, but instead if I look at the status, I get this error, and I can't seem to add anything:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 92 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I also tried

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but that just erases a lot of the files I pulled.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you create an empty repository on GitHub, make sure it is actually empty.

> have 92 and 1 different commits each, respectively.

That means the GitHub repository has *one* commit (typically a `README` file).
It does not matter: you will be able to force push to that GitHub repository, overriding its (small) history by your commits and your content.

Second, no need to clone anything: if you have already a folder cloned from your personal repo, where you are working, simply do (in that folder)

```
git config --add remote.origin.pushurl https://github.com/<me>/<my-empty-repo>.git
```

Any git push will then push to your personal repository *and* to GitHub as well.

The first push might need to be a `git push --force`, in order to override GitHub content and history.